# find file names containing a choice of strings

Tags: bash, find, pattern-matching

In the following example:

```
sudo find . -path "./*_parameterOne_*_*/*" -exec ./myScript.py {} +
```

... I actually just want to take files which are in, say

```
./aFolder/*_parameterOne_100_*/*
./aFolder/*_parameterOne_200_*/*
```

And exclude all other values (say 300, 400, etc). Is there a way to specify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the typical shell patterns:

```
find . -path "./*_parameterOne_[12]00_*/*" -exec ./myScript.py {} +
```

If you need more complex patterns, take a look at the options `-regex` and `-iregex`.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! Is there anything more flexible that lets me specify exactly which strings I want?   Like {string1, string2, string3}?

Comment: Um, yes? Read the last paragraph.

Comment: Sure. I had a look at `man find`. From what I understood, I have to specify again the whole path I already put after `-path` and then include in it a regular expression. I just can't figure out which syntax to use to allow a choice of strings. I'm sure it's just a matter of not finding the correct key words in google. :)

Comment: `find . -iregex '.*(subexpression 1|another expression).*`